# C++ Cannot pass string literal 'const char []' to a function with parameter type 'const T&' where T is typedef of char[]

Tags: c++

In the following code, the local variable `rcc` in `main()` and parameter `r` in `foo()` have the same type `const CC&`. The local variable is successfully assigned with a string literal, while passing of a string literal to `foo()` fails compilation. Why is there different behavior for the same type?

NOTE: Compiled in Visual Studio 2019

```
typedef char CC[5];

void foo(const CC& r)
{
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

void bar(const char(&r)[])
{
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const CC &rcc = "ex"; // Pass compilation with all standards
    const char(&rchar)[] = "ex"; // Pass compilation with all standards
    std::cout << rcc << ' ' << rchar << std::endl;
    bar("ex"); // Pass compilation with ISO C++20 standard only
    foo("ex"); // Fails compilation with all standards
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass a string literal to a function with parameter type `const T&` where `T` is a typedef of `char[]`.

I expected that assignment to a function parameter behaves the same as assignment to a local variable with the same type.

I received following compilation error:

```
error C2664: 'void foo(const CC (&))': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'const CC (&)'  
message : Reason: cannot convert from 'const char [3]' to 'const CC'  
message : There is no context in which this conversion is possible  
message : see declaration of 'foo'
```

Comment: @user17732522 Do you see the reason for successful compilation of the following (rchar is a local variable)? What is the difference between the two?  

const char(&rchar)[] = "ex";

Comment: "Dropping" bounds from array types has been allowed as an implicit qualification conversion (and by extension for direct reference binding) since C++20. See https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/565.

Answer (score 1):

`bar("ex");` is well-formed since C++20 because C++20 made it possible to implicitly drop array bounds from pointers/references to arrays. (See https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/565 and references therein.)

So the parameter of `bar` would since C++20 bind directly to the string literal.

---

I think `const CC &rcc = "ex";` should work because the first item in the chain of initialization rules that applies is [[dcl.init.ref]/5.4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.ref#5.4.2) according to which the reference is bound to a temporary materialized from a prvalue of the target type without reference qualifier that is implicitly converted to from the initializer expression.

"*implicitly converted*" is defined in [[conv.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#3) to be equivalent to a declaration of an imaginary variable `t` from the original initializer expression which in this case would be

```
const char t[5] = "ex";
```

This initialization would be well-formed because the rules for initialization of character arrays from string literals allow for leaving additional space in the array zero-initialized, see [[dcl.init.string]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#string-3).

So `rcc` would bind to a temporary (and lifetime-extended) `const char[5]` array initialized to the byte sequence `e`, `x`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`.

---

I think there should be no difference for `foo("ex");` either.

---

However I am not entirely sure this is the intended interpretation. Both GCC and Clang don't accept `const CC &rcc = "ex";` and I think there are a few problems with [conv.general]/3.